# Sort Vector by Type & Search by Type OR Derived Type

Tags: c++

I want to sort and search a vector by type (all inheriting from the same base). So far I've been utilizing `std::type_index` to compare types. My code looks like

```
bool compareType( Base* const& left, Base* const& right )
{
    return std::type_index( typeid( *left ) ) < std::type_index( typeid( *right ) );
}

std::vector<Base*> m_list;

template <typename T>
T* search()
{
    T example;
    auto it = std::lower_bound( m_list.begin(), m_list.end(), &example, compareType );
    if( it != m_list.end() )
    {
        return dynamic_cast<T*>( *it );
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

This has worked fine so far, but I now want my search method to also return any types that are derived from the one it's searching for and I have no clue how to go about that. For example

```
class Base {};
class DerivedA : public Base {};
class DerivedA1 : public DerivedA {};
class DerivedA1I : public DerivedA1 {};

// Calling this looks for a DerivedA, but can also return a DerivedA1 OR DerivedA1I
DerivedA* result = search<DerivedA>();
```

Comment: [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) might help you.

Comment: @NathanOliver is it worth mentioning `std::is_base_of` is C++11? Or do we already consider C++11 as common standard? (I know I do... :)

Comment: @user1810087 Yeah, C++11 should be pretty common.  The C++ tag means the current standard  (So C++14 right now) so unless they specify otherwise I assume I can use anything from the current standard on back

Comment: `std::is_base_of` is a compile-time check, won't work here, needs a runtime check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Base` is polymorphic, you may do:

```
std::vector<Base*> bases;

auto it = std::find(bases.begin(), bases.end(),
                    [](const auto* base) {
                        return dynamic_cast<const DerivedA*>(base) != nullptr;
                    });
```